# Query Builder or Closure or DQL, which is the right one for get ride of this complex SQL query with ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

So I've this two entities:

```
class TipoRegistro
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TipoTramite", inversedBy="tipoRegistros", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="nomencladores.tipo_registro_tipo_tramite", schema="nomencladores",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tipo_registro_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tipo_tramite_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $tipoTramites;
}

class TipoTramite
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TipoRegistro", mappedBy="tipoTramites", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $tipoRegistros;
}
```

I need to get all the `TipoRegistro` associated to `TipoTramite` trhough ManyToMany relationship as show before as the SQL below shows:

```
SELECT tr.* 
FROM
    nomencladores.tipo_registro tr
LEFT JOIN
    nomencladores.tipo_registro_tipo_tramite AS trtt
ON (trtt.tipo_registro_id = tr."id")
WHERE
    tr.activo = true
AND
    trtt.tipo_tramite_id = 1;
```

I don't know if I can use a custom repository here so my only solution is to use `query_builder` parameter at form level and this is what I'm doing:

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('tr')
        ->where('tr.activo = :activo')
        ->leftJoin('tr.tipoTramites', 'ttr')
        ->andWhere("ttr.tipo_tramite_id  = :tramite")
        ->setParameter("tramite", 1)
        ->setParameter('activo', true);
}
```

But that solution cause this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 121 near 'tipo_tramite_id': Error:
>   Class AppBundle\Entity\TipoTramite has no field or
>   association named tipo_tramite_id

I tried this one also (as suggested per user here):

```
->andWhere("ttr.tipoTramites  = :tramite")
```

But the errors turns into this one:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 120 near 'tipoTramites': Error: Invalid
>   PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or
>   SingleValuedAssociationField expected

Also I've tried this other solution:

```
->andWhere("tr.id = :tramite")
```

But this one doesn't return the right values. I read something about [`Closures`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) on the entity field type but has no idea in how to implement on this scenario. The other idea comes to me is use a DQL and a preparement statement but I thin this can't be used at form level, so I'm out of ideas, then how I can get those values? How I should establish the relation between this ManyToMany entities?

Comment: As you know the join in query will be handled by Doctrine, so you need to change the where clause to:  `->andWhere("tr.tipoTramites = :tramite")`

Comment: @Javad that turns into this error `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 120 near 'tipoTramites': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected` anyway I'm rewriting the post, give me some minutes and read again, I'm trying to be more clear

Comment: @Javad done, take a look please

Comment: Alright, so you want to add the joint table id in your query where clause; so I think it should be `->andWhere("ttr.id = :tramite")` not `->andWhere("ttr.tipoTramites  = :tramite")` and not `->andWhere("tr.id = :tramite")` then hopefully will produce proper query you want

Comment: @Javad that works but for be honest I don't know what this does, can you answer the question with the solution given some more explanations around it?

Comment: I did supply an answer I hope it helps and be good explanation how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a ManyToMany relationship in your entity, Doctrine will generate the third table as mediator between those two entities (named in `@ORM\JoinTable`) with two fields (defined in `joinColumns`). You do not have direct access to the fields or columns in the third table but they all will be handled by Doctrine in your DQL.
This means in your DQL you need to just set the joint table id in your where clause not the real field name and Doctrine will produce the proper SQL:

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
   return $er->createQueryBuilder('tr')
     ->where('tr.activo = :activo')
     ->leftJoin('tr.tipoTramites', 'ttr')
     ->andWhere("ttr.id  = :tramite")
     ->setParameter("tramite", 1)
     ->setParameter('activo', true);
}
```

This will produce the proper SQL.
*The only tip is you do not have access to the generated fields of third table in you DQL, but it will be handled by Doctrine and you can use the join table id instead*